# How to flatten a list with NULL values?

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to flatten this list but it's not working because of a NULL. I would like it to become `NA` when flattening the list. I am using the code below

```
list('hi','hello', NULL) %>% purrr::flatten_chr()
```

which retrieves an error

> Error: Can't coerce element 3 from a NULL to a character

I would like a solution in `purrr` because I am using it for some other manipulations before and after flattening the list.

Comment: The are arguments to `map_chr` that might help here.  I think the arguments exist in the CRAN version but I've only ever gotten things to work using the the current development version (0.2.2.9000): `list('hi','hello', NULL) %>% purrr::map_chr(1L, .default = NA)`

Answer (score 6):

It's not `purrr`, but it does work:

```
a <- list('hi','hello', NULL)
> sapply(a,function(x) ifelse(is.null(x),NA,x))
[1] "hi"    "hello" NA
```

Comment: Better solution than my proposal, I'd go with this one.

Comment: +1 but I forgot to mention in my answer that I prefer to stay on `purrr`. I was trying to use `purrr:map` instead of `sapply` with an `ifelse` to but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: got it `list('a','b',NULL) %>% 
  purrr::map(.x=., ~ifelse(is.null(.x), NA, .x))`

Answer (score 2):

```
list('hi','hello', NULL) %>% 
lapply(function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x)) %>% 
purrr::flatten_chr()
```

Maybe this works for you? first replace the NULL's, then flatten. Hope this helps.